# Working with static method Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, oop, static-methods

Good night guys!

I'm having the following problem ...
I have a web application that runs a "thread" that takes messages from the queue (MSMQ) ... Everything works correctly .. the problem is when I get this message, I can not display .. because the method that returns the message content is a "static" ..
I need to perform a function in JS to display this message.

conclusion:
The method "ProcessMessage" can not be named because he is not a static method ...
My main goal is to call a function in JS passing as parameter (m.Body.ToString ()) which is the content of the message.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

This is my code.

```
    public void StartThread()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                PrepareQueue();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }

    public static void PrepareQueue()
    {
        MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(".\\private$\\CTIQueue");
        myQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) });

        // Add an event handler for the ReceiveCompleted event.
        myQueue.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(MyReceiveCompleted);

        // Define wait handles for multiple operations.
        WaitHandle[] waitHandleArray = new WaitHandle[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Begin asynchronous operations.
            waitHandleArray[i] = myQueue.BeginReceive().AsyncWaitHandle;
        }

        // Specify to wait for all operations to return.
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandleArray);

        return;
    }

    private static void MyReceiveCompleted(Object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;

            // End the asynchronous receive operation.
            System.Messaging.Message m = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);
            ProcessMessage(m.Body.ToString()); <-- MY PROBLEM
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException)
        { }

        return;
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(string message)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "popup", "NewCaller('" + message + "');", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not instantiate an object of the class and call `ProcessMessage` on it? Static methods can instantiate an object of the enclosing `class` and invoke instance methods on it.

```
private static void MyReceiveCompleted(Object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;

        // End the asynchronous receive operation.
        System.Messaging.Message m = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);
        new MyClass().ProcessMessage(m.Body.ToString()); <-- MY PROBLEM
    }
    catch (MessageQueueException)
    { }

    return;
}
```

But if you are planning to invoke a client side code from server side, with reactive action happening at the server's end(which I think is your case) -- then I would prefer you use ASP.NET SignalR to signal the client that something interesting has happened at the server's end.